# Is there a way to test response is contained in schema?

Tags: karate

In Karate, I'd like to have a schema variable which is a superset of the response data so that I can test multiple requests with the same schema.

This should be specially useful for GraphQL, where the request itself defines the returned fields.

Expected schema:

```
{
   id: '#notnull',
   name: '#notnull',
   description: '##string',
   nonNullStringField: '#string'
   ...
}
```

```
Given url ...
When request ...
Then match response.data <contained in> '#(mySchema)'
```

Response.data:

```
{
   id: 'someId',
   name: 'some name'
}
```

In this case, all keys returned by the response.data should be in the schema, but any key in the schema not in the response.data should be ignored.

Is there a way to do that in Karate or some plan to add this feature going forward?

Edit: updated the example, since the only attribute being missed was a nullable one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not convinced an enhancement is needed, because the optional marker `##foo` was designed for this purpose, and this already works:

```
* def schema = { id: '#notnull', name: '#notnull', description: '##string' }
* def response = { id: 'someId', name: 'some name' }
* match response == schema
```

EDIT: but since you want to limit your schema to the keys in the response in a "generic" way, you can do this:

```
* def expected = {}
* def fun = function(k, v){ expected.put(k, schema[k]) }
* eval karate.forEach(response, fun)
* match response == expected
```

You should be able to easily create a re-usable JS or Java utility that achieves the above. A few reasons I'm not in favor of adding another syntax / `match` keyword is that nested JSON may have some interesting edge cases that will make this complex. And I don't want to complicate `match` any further. As I said in the comments, IMO schema validation is the last thing you need to test for in GraphQL, it is pretty much guaranteed. This is the first time anyone has requested this in 2 years, so there's that. You could consider submitting a PR of course :)

Comment: That's the solution I was thinking of for now, but the issue with that is that for GraphQL, ANY field may be missing and then testing for (database-level) required fields would not work, I believe.

Comment: In GraphQL, no fields (request-level) are actually required. I could very well request just a list of descriptions with no id or name (and the resulting JSON should not have any of those fields). But in the case I request the (database equivalent to) #notnull fields, they should never be null.

I tried doing something like:

```
* def idSchema = '#string'
* def schema = { id: '##(field)' }
```

But the test will pass both if the field is null or if the field is not present (this is a case where it should pass only if not present).

Comment: @CarlosRosa I give up, I am unable to understand you and how my edit has not solved what you need. feel free to request a PR by strictly following this process, all the best: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Also, this could be implemented with a variation of your code (do a forEach key in response, add the schema before the test), but the idea of choosing Karate and requesting a "contained in" is exactly so this does not need to be done manually for each test.

Comment: @CarlosRosa my current stand is I am not convinced this is needed. by the way, schema is the last thing you need to validate in GraphQL because everything is schema-driven in the first place, no worries if you disagree or decide to not use karate, peace.

Comment: Thank you for your support. Your statement about GraphQL makes sense and, though it was not my decision to use Karate in the first pace, I'm actually pretty impressed with the framework and would like to continue using it even if some of the tests will need to be done in a different way.

Comment: @CarlosRosa peace :) just 2 suggestions, a) you can easily create a re-usable utility function injected globally, that will be a one-liner in all your tests. b) don't force yourself to do the `match` in one step, for e.g. if you have a second expected schema JSON with all the required fields, you can do a `match contains` and solve your need with a second `match` step